# Shiny Calling Modules

Tags: r, module, shiny

Recently, I have made a lot of updates to one of the shinydashboards. Nothing too complex, but now the server script is becoming large and I wanted to modularize the code into sections. One thing is there a lot of user parameters and I wanted to place all of these in on script and source.

### Sourced Code

```
 mc_High_parameter <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$High <- renderUI({
        sliderInput("High", 'High Assumption:',
                    min = 0, max = .25,value = .1)
      })

    }
```

### Calling on the Server side

```
callModule(mc_High_parameter,'High')
```

### Displayed on the UI Side

```
uiOutput("High")
```

The App loads but the Slider is not displayed on the UI, I cannot really understand the issue. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiny modules take some getting used to, especially when working with renderUI. I'd take a look at [this GitHub page](https://gist.github.com/tbadams45/38f1f56e0f2d7ced3507ef11b0a2fdce) to help give you a sense of how to put it all together, and also read the [Shiny help page on the `session` object](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html), which is fundamental to modules.

In your specific case, here are a few changes to get it running:

**1. You need a UI module, which you hadn't included.** This is where you call `uiOutput`.

```
mc_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput(ns("High"))
  )
}
```

**2. You need to call the UI module within the `ui`.**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    mc_UI("High")
  )
)
```

**3. You need to use `session$ns()` in the id of your `sliderInput` so that the namespace is matched properly from the UI.**

```
mc_High_parameter <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$High <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(session$ns("High"), "High Assumption:",
            min = 0, max = .25,value = .1)
    })
}
```

**4. Ensure you call `session` in your `server` function.**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(mc_High_parameter,"High")
}
```

Comment: Awesome, detailed response. I appreciate it, saved me hours.